# java performance front : ref in for loop

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee

Which code is better for the performance point of you? I think second code because ref creation in for loop is not good.

May I know your opinion?

```
// First Code
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    SipSession abc = (SipSession) array1.get(i);
}

// Second Code
SipSession abc = null;
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    abc = (SipSession) array1.get(i);
}
```

Comment: I dont think the difference is worth losing sleep over, I would prefer the first for readability, though you should profile if this is important to you

Comment: The more likely optimisation would come from not casting, removing the repeated call to size (though may well be inlined) and converting the list (presumably) into an actual array before this loop.

Answer (score 3):

You should only choose on performance grounds after you've profiled your code and established that this is the bottleneck.

Until you've done that, choose whichever version you think is clearer an easier to maintain.

I would always choose the first version except when I need the last `SipSession` reference to outlive the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately it will make no difference. The JIT will optimize that code away to exactly the same thing.

The only difference is the scope, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's much performance difference between the two. Only major difference is the scope of the `SipSession` reference. But you should try profiling if you care *that* much.

Comment: you should try profiling if you care that much.Through profiling, what i ll find out in this code. Time taken by for loop ?

Answer (score 0):

In your first code the VM or even the compiler will simply remove the reference variable, because it is never used within its scope.

It will be optimized to

```
for(int i=0;i<array.size();i++){
    array1.get(i);    
}
```

Depending of what is done in the `get` method the hole loop may be removed while optimization.

If the order the elements are accessed is not important you can also:

```
for (int i = array.size()-1; 0 <= i ;) {
    SipSession abc = (SipSession) array1.get(i--);
}
```

This would call `array.size()` only once instead of in each loop iteration.

Comment: You may run into problems with backwards loops not being optimised. (Last info I can remember is that hardware is well optimised for it, but HotSpot is not.)

Comment: @Tom Hawtin: The optimization is not the backwards loop. The optimization is the avoidance of all the method calls `array.size()`.

Comment: The major change is that the loop runs backwards. If you wanted to remove the multiple calls to `size()`, `final int size = array.size();` would be the way to do it.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin: I doubt that the extra line of code and the extra variable in the outer scope will be any better. I think only profiling the different version will show the benefit, if one exists.

Answer (score 0):

This would be **Micro Optimization** and its better to do other kinds of optimizations of code than doing them without proof that it is the bottleneck. Which is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Never try to optimize without profiling. The JIT compiler does the heavy lifting *so you don't have to*.

That aside, your `array` seems to be a raw `List` instead of a generic `List<SipSession>`. Generics won't necessarily optimize your code, but it makes it much easier to understand and maintain. Your simple loop could be rewritten as:

```
List<SipSession> array;
for(SipSession abc : array){
    // Stuff    
}
```